# Convert quaternions to xyz degrees

Tags: geometry, quaternions, angle

I knew quaternion for the first time a few days ago and I still don't get the way it works even when reading explanations.
All I want to do is to make a subtraction between two quaternions and convert the variations into XYZ angles (radians or degrees) but I don't know from where I have to start… Can I simply subtract values one by one to make the difference?
If I apply the equations written on [this site](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/index.htm), what will be the unit of the results?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Subtracting one quaternion from another does not have any real interpretation as a rotation. Can you elaborate what your ultimate goal is? What are the two transformations you are "doing subtraction" with?

Comment: Well, I have to make rotate a camera in a 3D space for a web application. We can move the camera when touching the screen (with variations of finger's position), and with device orientation.
I've already handled the movements with fingers and device orientation separately, but when I try to add them both it doesn't go right. As I already made a camera.rotateUp and camera.rotateLeft functions (with radians variation as a parameter) to handle the touch' related rotation, I wanted to convert quaternion to radians or degrees to make the difference easily and then apply it to my application.

Comment: Don't these events occur sequentially? A small finger movement and then a small change of device orientation and so on, with each individual change small enough to give the appearance of smooth movement? If so, simply combining the steps from both inputs should be the same as combining multiple steps from the same input. Apparently it's not, so you must be doing something different than I'd expect, but I don't see what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I knew quaternion for the first time a few days ago and I still don't get the way it works even when reading explanations.

Don't get discouraged, some of the concepts take a while.

> All I want to do is to make a subtraction between two quaternions

As [@rschwieb](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29335/rschwieb) wrote in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652055/convert-quaternions-to-xyz-degrees#comment3370329_1652055), subtracting quaternions doesn't make a lot of sense geometrically. That's because quaternions as rotations operate multiplicative: you get the combination of two rotations by multiplying the quaternions, not by adding them. So the analogon to a difference of rotation angles would be the quotient of two quaternions.

> convert the variations into XYZ angles

The Wikipedia page [Rotation formalisms in three dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions) has a nice overview of different formalisms and how to convert between them. In particular, you should be precise whether “XYZ angles” refers to [*simultaneous* rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_orthogonal_rotations_angle) around all three axes, or to sequential rotation around each of these axes in the sense of [Tait–Bryan angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles).

> If I apply the equations written on this site, what will be the unit of the results?

I haven't read all that, but unless stated otherwise I'd assume radians, since degrees are a pretty arbitrary choice of unit, while radians have deep mathematical connections. Also most programming languages, and definitely the Java used there, represent angles for their trigonometric functions in radians by default.

Comment: Thanks for you explanations.  
I understand now why the values I got when subtracting Q2.x-Q1.x where awkward! So, based on what you said I have to take the quotient of two quaternions and then convert it in radians, seems simple!  
In the code I am using, I found a comment saying `// The angles alpha, beta and gamma form a set of intrinsic Tait-Bryan angles of type Z-X'-Y''`.
  Does it make a difference for my equations?

Comment: I tried to apply the equations the way I wrote before, but I think I am doing everything wrong. Still based on the site I linked before, I am supposed to have:  an angle, x, y and z.
What is this "angle"? If x, y and z aren't angles, what do they are supposed  to represent? Axes? So there is one angle for 3axes?
Here is for example the quaternion of my camera ([image link](http://i.imgur.com/G7KEUU3.png)), how can I manage to have "normal" angles? (for example: 30° from x, 40° from y).
I think I still don't get the way quaternions work.

Comment: @P.Ellul: Sure the order and axes for chained rotations matters; intrinsic $Z-X'-Y''$ is different from e.g. extrinsic $Z-X-Z$. Which one you need depends on what you want to achieve. With an angle and axis desription you have one angle (i.e. a number) and a vector indicating the axis, consisting of three coordinates $x,y,z$. This example “30° from x, 40° from y” sounds like you'd want to compute the angle between lines, not the angle of rotation. That doesn't fit in well with your comment about the camera controls.

Comment: I want to calculate from two quaternions, the rotations that have been made. Let's say Q1 is the quaternion of the rotation where the camera starts from, and Q2 is the new rotation values the computer got. I want to extract from these two quats the rotations that have been made around x, y and z axis to compute them after. Thanks again for you helpful answers